# Why is this method not executing?

Tags: java, methods, random

I am writing a program that generates a random number, then has the user guess the number. I have two methods:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
//Declares methods to be used during process
generateNumber();
playGame();
}
```

The first method `generateNumber()` executes fine. The code looks like this:

```
public static void generateNumber()
{
//Generates number and assigns it to the variable "randomNumber"
System.out.println("Generating random number between 0 and 100. Please wait.");
Random rand = new Random();
int randomNumber = rand.nextInt(101) + 1;
System.out.println("Random number generated");
}
```

The process then ends and the second method `playGame()`:

```
public static void playGame()
{  
//Asks for guess of the number. Prints whether the guess is above or below randomNumber.
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
while(userGuess != randomNumber){
   System.out.println("Guess the number ");
   userGuess = reader.nextInt(); 

  if (userGuess > randomNumber) {
     numberOfGuesses++;
     System.out.println("Incorrect! The number that you guessed is greater than my number!");
  } else {
     numberOfGuesses++;
     System.out.println("Incorrect! The number that you guessed is less than my number!"); 
      }

if(userGuess == randomNumber){
System.out.println("Correct! My number was "+randomNumber+". It took you "+numberOfGuesses+" tries to find my number!");
  }
}
}
```

The formatting may be bad, but I just transferred it over from JCreator and it was all messed up. I'm sure that it's something very simple, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: your code cannot compile

Comment: how do i fix it though?

Comment: What is the behaviour? What is the error? Is there is no error, what are you expecting to happen and what have you observed?

Comment: the error if you read it is that the second method isnt executed

Comment: can we initialize int userGuess = -1;  ? before while loop ?

Comment: "The formatting may be bad, but I just transferred it over from JCreator and it was all messed up." Regardless of whether or not that is true, you could go over your question and clear up the formatting before submitting. That last look over the code also gives you an opportunity to find bugs you might have overlooked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `randomNumber` is a local variable in `generateNumber()` and you try to access it in `playGame()`.

You must either use a global variable, or better yet give the random number as a parameter to `playGame()`

```
public static int generateNumber()
{
//Generates number and assigns it to the variable "randomNumber"
System.out.println("Generating random number between 0 and 100. Please wait.");
Random rand = new Random();
int randomNumber = rand.nextInt(101) + 1;
System.out.println("Random number generated");
return randomNumber;
}

public static void playGame(int randomNumber)
{
...
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
//Declares methods to be used during process
int randomNumber = generateNumber();
playGame(randomNumber);
}
```

*Update:*

The problem with printing both "Correct" and "Incorrect" lies in the structure of the `if` statements

```
if (userGuess > randomNumber) {
    // incorrect
} else {
    // incorrect
}

if (userGuess == randomNumber) {
    // correct
}
```

When you have `guess == random`, it will go into the `else` part *and* in the second `if`. To solve this, you must chain all `if`s together, so the program will select only one of the three branches, e.g.

```
if (userGuess == randomNumber) {
    // correct
} else if (userGuess > randomNumber) {
    // incorrect
} else {
    // incorrect
}
```

Comment: yes! that worked! thank you! also, whenever I run the program, even though I get the answer right and it prints the "Correct!" line, it says the "Incorrect!" line right before the process ends. any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: ah, I understand. That makes a lot of sense. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Your random number is declared in one method, but it's referenced in the other.

```
int randomNumber = rand.nextInt(101) + 1;
```

You need to declare it in the class scope.

Comment: so move that to the main method?

Comment: @user3033159 No, not inside the main method.  Just declare the variable at the class level (outside of any methods) and just set the value in `generateNumber()`.

Comment: public static int randomNumber;? because i did that at the top of the program, i just didnt include that part of the code

Comment: @user3033159 It doesn't need to be `public`, but that should work.  Also remove `int` from the line of code above in your `generateNumber` method, otherwise it will redeclare the variable in the local scope.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Bill The Lizard said, you don't seem to be declaring number of guesses anywhere, nor do you declare userGuess. You have to declare both of them, probably at function scope.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have missing the declaration of the `userGuess` variable.

EDIT: And, also the `randomNumber` variable is not declared in the second method. You should declare it in the class as a static filed.

Comment: userGuess = reader.nextInt();

Comment: that is not a declaration, that's the definition. There should be "int userGuess;" somewhere

Comment: its defined at the top of the program. i didn't show that part, im sorry.

Comment: ok, so try also to put the randomNumber in there.